# converting Biginteger to Bytearray(Raw data)

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c

I have used the following code for converting the bigint in decimal to bytearray (raw data), but I'm getting wrong result.

What is the mistake here?

I'm trying this in Apple Mac ( for Iphone app)
COMP_BYTE_SIZE is 4

Is there any bigendian/ little endian issue, please Help.

```
void bi_export(BI_CTX *ctx, bigint *x, uint8_t *data, int size)
{
    int i, j, k = size-1;

    check(x);
    memset(data, 0, size);  /* ensure all leading 0's are cleared */

    for (i = 0; i < x->size; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < COMP_BYTE_SIZE; j++)
        {
            comp mask = 0xff << (j*8);
            int num = (x->comps[i] & mask) >> (j*8);
            data[k--] = num;

            if (k < 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: The size is 309 which is length from a decimal Char*

Somehow i am getting the first 4 bytes are correct and the end 4 bytes are correct even i cast to (int8_t)num

Thanks

Comment: This below code is working for smal integer value 
barray[0] =(unsigned char)(num &0xff); 
barray[1] =(unsigned char)((num>>8) & 0xff); 
barray[2] =(unsigned char)((num>>16) &0xff); 
barray[3] = (unsigned char)((num)>> 24); 
any clue ?

Comment: Maybe you should give us an example of an x->comps with the data you expect and the wrong data you get.

Comment: probably mask is an issue, try replace your loop with
for(i = 0; i < x->size; i++)
{
   int num = x->comps[i];
   for (j = 0; j < COMP_BYTE_SIZE; j++)
   { 
       data[k--] = (uint8_t)(num >> (j*8)); 

       if (k < 0) 
       { 
            break; 
       } 
}

Comment: First few bytes and some end bytes of the correct data are
-93 -109 106 -102 101 -90 -5 -2 119 45 -105 ......69 96 -110 -106 -63 -83 100 -50 14
The Wrong data are
35 -109  106 102 50 -45 125 -1 29 -53 101 -33.....21 65 37 45 -125 45 100 -50 14

comparing both only few bytes in start and end are same others are wrong , I have tried Andy suggestion above also but the result remains same  , thanks

Comment: uint8_t is an unsigned type, yet you output it signed with negative values. Thus it may as well be that the values in data are correct, but your verification goes wrong. It is at least an indication that you don't exactly know what you're doing there. When I then look into your profile and see that you seem to use this for cryptography and security, it gives me an ice cold shudder. I strongly suggest that you first learn all about this stuff -- signed and unsigned integer types, values and representation, different number systems and all this.

Comment: When My test decimal Data is  char *i6 = "12345678910";
Java gives Correct Result   { 2 ,-33 ,-36 ,28 ,62}
But the above C code give wrong result   {5  ,95  ,-36  ,28  ,62  }  only the last 3 bytes are always correct !!!

when the test data is shrink to the minimum as 
char *i6 = "1234567891";
Both Java and C   give the same correct Result       { 73 ,-106 ,2 ,-45}
But the above c method supposed to work for BigInteger  
I have tried this in ANSI C with Windows and Mac both same result , is this Logic work for biginteger (shft by 8) or any other logic available for converting toBytearr

Comment: Please post the complete code. Probably there is an issue with how you invoke the function and verify the data.

Comment: My Calling code  in c:
char *i6 = "56785678910123456789";
    printf("char arr length::: %d \n",strlen(i6));
    int len = strlen(i6)/2;
    bi6 = str_to_bi( i6 );
    FILE *res;
    res= fopen("rfile","w");
    bi_print(res,bi_copy(bi6));
    fclose(res);
    int8_t *data = malloc(len);
    bi_export(bi6, data, len);
    printf("test arr {");
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
     {
  printf("%d  ,",data[i]);
     }
    printf("}");

Result:  char arr length::: 20 
bigint chars length::: 3 
test arr {0  ,12  ,40  ,30  ,-124  ,53  ,119  ,76  ,-71  ,21  ,}

Comment: Actual C Code
typedef int64_t comp;
struct _real_bigint {
    int refs; struct _real_bigint* next;int num_comps, max_comps;   int sign;
    comp* comps; };
typedef struct _real_bigint* real_bigint;
void bi_export( bigint obi, int8_t *data, int size){
    int i, j,k = size-1;memset(data, 0, size);  
    real_bigint bi = (real_bigint) obi;
    for (i = 0; i < bi->num_comps; i++)    {
        for (j = 0; j < COMP_BYTE_SIZE; j++) {
            comp mask = 0xff << (j*8);
            int num = (bi->comps[i] & mask) >> (j*8); data[k--] = num;            if (k < 0) {break;}}}}

Comment: Post the function defintion for str_to_bi

Comment: Hi Andy 
    That function is validated correct.As i can verify the converted binteger to write to a file and find the same Decimal string.
bigint
str_to_bi( char* str )
    {
    int sign;
    bigint biR;

    sign = 1;
    if ( *str == '-' )
 {
 sign = -1;
 ++str;
 }
    for ( biR = bi_0; *str >= '0' && *str <= '9'; ++str )
 biR = bi_int_add( bi_int_multiply( biR, 10 ), *str - '0' );
    if ( sign == -1 )
 biR = bi_negate( biR );
    return biR;
    }

Comment: I have tried the same c code in windows also giving the "same "incorrect result , so there is no issue about MAc specific Endian/compiler/byte representation issues ! So it is the logic which does not work for BigInteger? OR i am doing some thing wrong ? , Hope someone help me !!!!

Comment: Check how the bigint is created and returned. I find in many places it is created locally and returned to the calling function.
Edit your question and put the complete code (a compilable version). Again some dependency like bi_int_add and bi_int_multiply are required to compile the code.

Comment: Hi Andy
  Please send email to my address i can pass the code bos1tech@gmail.com

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The argument size is at least x->size*4, ie. the target array is big enough? Also use

```
comp mask = (comp)0xff << (j*8);
```

Answer (score 0):

`num` should be cast to `uint8_t` before copy

```
data[k--] = (uint8_t)num;
```

Comment: Somehow i am getting the first 4 bytes are correct and the end 4 bytes are correct even i cast to (int8_t)num Thanks

Comment: First few bytes and some end bytes of the correct data are -93 -109 106 -102 101 -90 -5 -2 119 45 -105 ......69 96 -110 -106 -63 -83 100 -50 14 The Wrong data are 35 -109 106 102 50 -45 125 -1 29 -53 101 -33.....21 65 37 45 -125 45 100 -50 14 comparing both only few bytes in start and end are same others are wrong , I have tried Andy suggestion above also but the result remains same , thanks

Comment: when i tried converting for simple decimal value "123456789"
 in java i am getting 
the byte string is as below 
The Data in byte:: 7
The Data in byte:: 91
The Data in byte:: -51
The Data in byte:: 21

But in mac with the above code i am getting 

The Data in byte:: 35
The Data in byte:: 69
The Data in byte:: 103
The Data in byte:: -119

so is that Mask is wrong , pleas advice

Comment: in Java  the result is                        7 , 91 ,-51 , 21
in Mac with the above c code  the result is   35 , 69, 103, -119

what is the wrong in the code  , Please help

Comment: I am not able to find what is the issue with Mac code. Did you try the code snippet which I had given above with this input.

Comment: Yes i tried with the same above c code but i am compiling and runnning in Xcode in Mac  , Any difference in compiler/Mask / Endian or byte representation ?

Thanks

Comment: When My test decimal Data is  char *i6 = "12345678910";
Java gives Correct Result   { 2 ,-33 ,-36 ,28 ,62}
But the above C code give wrong result   {5  ,95  ,-36  ,28  ,62  }  only the last 3 bytes are always correct !!!

when the test data is shrink to the minimum as 
char *i6 = "1234567891";
Both Java and C   give the same correct Result       { 73 ,-106 ,2 ,-45}
But the above c method supposed to work for BigInteger  
I have tried this in ANSI C with Windows and Mac both same result , is this Logic work for biginteger (shft by 8) or any other logic available for converting toBytearr